# Is there any way that a single search can encompass different indices at the same time in azure search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm searching through the Azure search REST APIs, I have a data source, a set of cognitive skills, an index and an indexer, when I do any type of search from a data source with a single index, it performs the search correct, but if I have different indexes with others data source only the result of one of the indices will return.

my question is: how in a single search can I cover different indices at the same time and return the results I find from the different indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Azure Search does not support searching over multiple indexes in a single query.

Please consider upvoting the ['Search multiple indexes at once' feature in Azure Search’s user-voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/16700506-search-multiple-indexes-at-once) to help us to set feature priorities.